# What is the diference between $\lambda x.1$ and $1$?

Tags: lambda-calculus

I know that I can $(\lambda x.1) 0 \rhd_\beta 1$. This is the constant 1, but can I contract it automatically? I mean, is $1$ the normal form of $(\lambda x.1)$?

It seems reasonable to do it but when goes to combinators this sense stops, I mean, if I can $\lambda x.1 \rhd_\beta 1$, then I would $\lambda xy.y \rhd_\beta \lambda y.y$ but $(\lambda xy.y) a b \rhd_\beta b$ and $(\lambda x.1) a b \rhd_\beta 1 b$ so that $\lambda x.1 \not\equiv_\beta 1$

What rules I'm missing on Lambda cauculus that forbids the contraction $\lambda x.1 \rhd_\beta 1$?

Comment: $\lambda x.1$ is a function that gets $x$ as input and outputs $1$. In contrast, $1$ is just $1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\lambda$-contraction is defined as $(\lambda v.M)N \triangleright_\beta M[v/N]$. A $\lambda$-term of the form $(\lambda v.M)N$ is called a **redex** (= reducible expression). In order to reduce a term, you need a redex -- that's just how $\lambda$-contraction is defined.
The reason that $\lambda x.1$ can not be any further reduced is that it does not contain any redex: It is not and does not contain any terms of the form $(\lambda v.M)N$, so $\lambda$-contraction is just not applicable anywhere. The term thus already is in normal form.
In contrast, $(\lambda x.1)0$ contains a redex, namely itself -- with $v = x$, $M = 1$ and $N = 0$ --, and $\lambda$-contraction yields the normal form $1$.
Obviously $\lambda x.1$ and $1$ are non-equivalent normal forms: One is a function that yields a number, the other one is a number.
$(\lambda x.1)$ is different from $(\lambda x.1)0$ in the same way in which, say, $f: x \mapsto x^2$ is different from $f(2)\ (= 4)$. A function is not the same as the value of the function at an argument, and a function can not be applied to yield a value without an argument present.

Comment: Hmm redex was the missing bit. So only applications are redexes!?

Comment: Yes, and only applications where the left part is an abstraction. E.g. $((\lambda x.x)(\lambda y.y))(1)$ would not be itself a redex, because the term on the left is an application, not an abstraction. (But though the term as a whole is not a redex, it *contains* the redex $((\lambda x.x)(\lambda y.y))$, which can be contracted to $\lambda y.y$, yielding a new redex $(\lambda y.y)1$, which reduces to $1$.)

Comment: Thank you @lemontree, I will implement call by value semantics this will be very useful, if you got curious https://github.com/dhilst/funcyou/blob/master/lambdac.py it's a weekend project but it's being fun :)

Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi @lemontree. I was wondering on your example, $((\lambda x.x)(\lambda y.y))(1)$. Thinking about CBC I would $((\lambda x.x)(\lambda y.y))(1) \rightarrow (\lambda x.x)1 \rightarrow 1$ right?

Comment: No. There is no free variable in $(\lambda y.y)$ and no abstraction in $x$ that would lead to capturing, so no renaming is needed and the  intermediate result is $(\lambda y.y)1$.

Comment: well, sorry, that was just me being lazy, since $\lambda x.x \equiv_\alpha \lambda y.y$ I thought that that wouldn't be a problem, thanks!

Comment: With $\equiv_\alpha$ included in $\triangleright_\beta$, it's equialent, yes. It's just not part of the elementary contraction.

Comment: Hi @lemontree I would like to share with you my implementation and output of doctests :) thank you for the help :) https://github.com/dhilst/funcyou/blob/master/lambdac.py https://gist.github.com/dhilst/63c21e6968335ae457bb7572dc1fc5a2

To run the doctests is just a matter of python3 -m doctest lambdac.py (you need pyparsing installed too :))

Thanks again you helped a lot. I will try to add types to it after reviewing what was done

Comment: For feedback on your code, I suggest you ask at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and state specifically which parts you are unsure about.

Comment: Oh cool, I didn't how that exchange subdomain.Thank you! I will post it there :)